# Can I get my drobo to let me use a whole (single) drive instead of reserving half of it for expansion?

Tags: drobo

In the future, I will buy more drives and make use of the drobo's failure protection, but for now I have just one drive in it. Is there a way to get it to let me use the whole disk instead of only half? I'm using it as a backup of other disks, so I don't need redundant redundancy :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I read when I looked into Drobo a while ago there is no way to turn this off. I just looked at their support site and it seems like when a single drive is used, half of it is reserved to mirror the data. This way if you run into data corruption or other unexpected problems, you are still protected. It does not protect again drive failure (obviously). If you want to use a single drive you should use either a SATA-to-USB cable or an enclosure. The Drobo is made as a drive protection device, therefore you are stuck with that functionality for the good and the bad.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that this option is only available in the driver of the DroboPro.

From the drobo [site](http://www.drobo.com/resources/beyondraid.php):

> The BeyondRAID featured on DroboPro
>   even allows IT managers to switch from
>   single to dual disk redundancy with a
>   single click, thereby ensuring
>   enterprise-level dual parity data
>   protection if required.

Comment: This is not correct. It is not possible to turn off redundancy completely, even with DroboPro. Switching to "Single disk redundancy" means the data will only be written to two drive (the original plus on backup) where "dual disk redundancy" means the data is written to three drives (the original plus TWO backups). Switching to single disk redundancy will NOT allow the user to use the entire single disk; they will only get half (even with DroboPro).